# 'str' object has no attribute: 'descendants' in BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get pizza discounts using the bs4 library in python. However, no matter what I try, I always get the same error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'`. Will someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
url = requests.get('https://www.papajohns.com/order/specials')
data = url.content
items = soup(data, 'html.parser')
discount_list = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'description'}).text
for each_item in discount_list:
    print(each_item.text)
```

Comment: the website is down I suppose

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes in your code:

You are calling the `beautifulsoup` which you imported as `soup` library instead of the `items` object in the line 6. You also need to remove the `.text` attribute like @Cz_ suggested. Change this line like this:

```
discount_list = items.find_all('p', {'class': 'description'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing .text too many times. You have

```
discount_list = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'description'}).text
for each_item in discount_list:
    print(each_item.text)
```

which has `.text` twice, on the first line and in the print. Therefore you're essentially trying to do `.text.text`, and since the first `.text` is a `str` and has no descendants, which is what the second `.text` would be, you're getting that error.

To solve it, simply change the `discount_list` line to

```
discount_list = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'description'})
```

Comment: I also tried and still get the same error also after removing `.text` in the discount_list declaration.

Comment: Ah yep, see the other persons answer. If it's not that, then it's because of the URL you're trying to do. Modern webpages are so often filled with scripts and redirects that parsing with BS4 directly is often a pain or impossible.

Comment: Yes. But there is also a other mistake. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is when you make a url request for the webpage, it automatically redirects you to a different webpage when there are no specials available.

I tried going to that webpage, but was unable to navigate without being redirected.